# Unable to scrape website for price element

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I wanted to scrape name, roast and price and I have succesfully done it with the code below. However I am not able to scrape the price . it shows up as 'None'.

```
URLS = ["https://www.thirdwavecoffeeroasters.com/products/vienna-roast","https://www.thirdwavecoffeeroasters.com/products/baarbara-estate","https://www.thirdwavecoffeeroasters.com/products/el-diablo-blend","https://www.thirdwavecoffeeroasters.com/products/organic-signature-filter-coffee-blend","https://www.thirdwavecoffeeroasters.com/products/moka-pot-express-blend-1","https://www.thirdwavecoffeeroasters.com/products/karadykan-estate","https://www.thirdwavecoffeeroasters.com/products/french-roast","https://www.thirdwavecoffeeroasters.com/products/signature-cold-brew-blend","https://www.thirdwavecoffeeroasters.com/products/bettadakhan-estate","https://www.thirdwavecoffeeroasters.com/products/monsoon-malabar-aa"]

for url in range(0,10):
    req=requests.get(URLS[url])
    soup = bs(req.text,"html.parser")
    coffees = soup.find_all("div",class_="col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12")
    for coffee in coffees:
        name = coffee.find("div",class_="product-details-main").find("ul",class_="uk-breadcrumb uk-text-uppercase").span.text
        roast = coffee.find("div",class_="uk-flex uk-flex-middle uk-width-1-1 coff_type_main").find("p",class_="coff_type uk-margin-small-left uk-text-uppercase").text.split("|")[0]
        prices = coffee.find("div",class_="uk-width-1-1 uk-first-column")

        
        
        
        
    print(name,roast,price)
```

Comment: Similar to your question yesterday, if you print soup it will show you that the selector for prices doesn't exist

Comment: If you save the `req.text` into a file and try to look for the price using ctrl+c, you will see that it's not included in the HTML page. It's likely that the page is loaded dynamically by JavaScript. If you look closely in `req.text`, there is a global variable called `meta` at line 107. That JavaScript object contains all the product prices in a convenient JSON format. You may decide to look for that instead and parse it with the `json` library using `json.loads()`. Good luck!

Comment: You may want to revisit your previous questions from the last days, look at responses, accept the ones that helped you, and apply those responses in your work. You might have more success.

Comment: Another thing to point out, the code snippet you shared references a `price` variable that is not defined. Also, the indentation of the last print statement is off. Try to be more careful when you post your questions on Stack Overflow (or any other website, for that matter)

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that in the response you are not getting the HTML element you are looking for. If you search for the price element in `req.text`, you won't find it. This is probably because the website renders the page dynamically with JavaScript.

If you look closely in `req.text`, however, you can find all the coffee variants with their respective price in the `meta` JavaScript object. You can look for it and parse it into a Python dictionary using the `loads()` function from the `json` library.

Here is your working code that also prints the prices. Note that all prices are multiplied by 100, so you may need to account for that.

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import json

URLS = ["https://www.thirdwavecoffeeroasters.com/products/vienna-roast","https://www.thirdwavecoffeeroasters.com/products/baarbara-estate","https://www.thirdwavecoffeeroasters.com/products/el-diablo-blend","https://www.thirdwavecoffeeroasters.com/products/organic-signature-filter-coffee-blend","https://www.thirdwavecoffeeroasters.com/products/moka-pot-express-blend-1","https://www.thirdwavecoffeeroasters.com/products/karadykan-estate","https://www.thirdwavecoffeeroasters.com/products/french-roast","https://www.thirdwavecoffeeroasters.com/products/signature-cold-brew-blend","https://www.thirdwavecoffeeroasters.com/products/bettadakhan-estate","https://www.thirdwavecoffeeroasters.com/products/monsoon-malabar-aa"]


for url in URLS:
    req=requests.get(url)

    soup = bs(req.text,"html.parser")
    coffees = soup.find_all("div",class_="col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12")
    for coffee in coffees:
        name = coffee.find("div",class_="product-details-main").find("ul",class_="uk-breadcrumb uk-text-uppercase").span.text
        roast = coffee.find("div",class_="uk-flex uk-flex-middle uk-width-1-1 coff_type_main").find("p",class_="coff_type uk-margin-small-left uk-text-uppercase").text.split("|")[0]
        
        print(name,roast)

    # Find the JavaScript declaration (there is only one `meta` variable, so no chance of ambiguity)
    json_start = req.text.find("var meta = ") + len("var meta = ")
    # Find the end of the JavaScript object (there won't be any `;` inside)
    json_end = req.text.find(";",json_start) 
    json_str = req.text[json_start:json_end]
    json_data = json.loads(json_str)

    # Get the prices from the JSON object
    product = json_data["product"]
    variants = product["variants"]
    for variant in variants:
        print(f'Variant: {variant["name"]}, price: {variant["price"]}')
    
    print("\n")
```

I hope this helps, cheers.

Comment: Yes it is similar to my last question . I still don't understand it completely but in parts the explanation help. How would I save this in an excel ?